# Simple PHP Update query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which should check the posted field and update an associated row in a sql table incrementally i.e. the number should increase each time. I've tried this a few different ways but unable to get this working - any help appreciated.

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']))
{
    $username =($_POST['username']);
    mysql_query("
        UPDATE users 
        SET refer = refer +1
        WHERE Username = '".$username."'
    ");
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not use the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface which was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Here parameters are **NOT** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and this has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Escape **any** and all user data, especially from `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: if someone inputs `x' OR '1' = '1` in the input you're going to have some nasty stuff happening

Comment: what is the  "Error" ?

Comment: no error as such, the db just doesnt update

Comment: do code inside `if` is ever executed? (do you debug it by for example `var_dump`) ?

Comment: You're not even checking for errors. Add `or die(mysql_error())` to the end of the `mysql_query()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomend you use the php 7 and PDO, the mysql_query its obsolete :

Make something like:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');

if (!empty($_POST['username'])) {
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET refer = :refer WHERE Username = :username");

$stmt->execute([
    'refer' => refer + 1,
    'username' => $_POST['username']
]);
}
```

Comment: `refer + 1` is not a valid PHP expression unless `refer` is a defined constant.

Comment: Sorry I forget to put the "$", but yeah we can use "SET refer = refer + 1" on query also.

Comment: The missing `$` isn't the whole problem, you never set `$refer` in the first place.